# DataFrame: Append column name to rows data

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm looking a way to append column names to data frame row's data . 
Number of columns could be different from time to time

I've Spark 1.4.1

I've a dataframe :

**Edit:** : all data is `String` type only

```
+---+----------+
|key|     value|
+---+----------+
|foo|       bar|
|bar|  one, two|
+---+----------+
```

I'd like to get :

```
  +-------+---------------------+
  |key    |                value|
  +-------+---------------------+
  |key_foo|            value_bar|
  |key_bar| value_one, value_two|
  +---+-------------------------+
```

I tried

```
 import org.apache.spark.sql._
 import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

 val concatColNamesWithElems = udf { seq: Seq[Row] =>
     seq.map { case Row(y: String) => (col +"_"+y)}}
```

Comment: what type is your `value` column?

Comment: @mtoto `value` has `String` values only

Answer (score 1):

**Save DataFrame as Table (Ex: `dfTable`)**, So that you write SQL on it.

```
df.registerTempTable("dfTable")
```

**Create UDF and Register**: I'd assume your `value` column type is `String`

```
sqlContext.udf.register("prefix", (columnVal: String, prefix: String) =>
  columnVal.split(",").map(x => prefix + "_" + x.trim).mkString(", ")
)
```

**Use UDF in Query**

```
//prepare columns which have UDF and all column names with AS 
//Ex: prefix(key, "key") AS key // you can this representation 
val columns = df.columns.map(col => s"""prefix($col, "$col") AS $col """).mkString(",")


println(columns) //for testing how columns framed

val resultDf = sqlContext.sql("SELECT " + columns + " FROM dfTable")
```

Comment: Thanks for fast answer ! As I understand only col names `"key"` ,`"value"` will work . Unfortunately, column names and number of columns could be variant each time I execute the code . I look for more general solution

Comment: You can use udf like `prefixCol(column_name_in_table, "prefix_string")` in `select`. With this you can add any prefix to the values in column.

Comment: @Toren: this udf provides maximum generic solution. Let me know if you think this won't work in generic way. _As I understand only col names "key" ,"value" will work_ **It works with any column(string type) and any prefix**.

Comment: I'm still thinking how to loop over whole `df`(all columns) with this solution

Comment: Depends , could be various

Comment: Pls check the edit. I made a solution with iterating over all columns and prepare column list for `SELECT` with `df.columns`

Comment: I get error when try to create `resultDf`:`java.lang.RuntimeException: [3.7] failure: ``union'' expected but ErrorToken(illegal character) found $columns ` (Spark 1.4.1)

Comment: Try to include `columns` to select query in java way with `+` operator.

Comment: Can you please update solution with latest suggestion ? 10x

Comment: Unfortunately still fails with `java.lang.NullPointerException` , I can't understand why ...